# Bootstrap 4 nav tab active tab issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap@4.0.0-beta and I'm created the four `nav tab` I'm try to do  I'm click some page after display 4 navtab, but I want to display click the page display 4 navtab  after   active **Spaces** button  and click another tab active another navtab ,and  no need active previous tab button.

Look my code sample, my space button is always active,please help me to fix the issue.

```css
/*footer-navtab*/

.footer-tab .tooter-nav-tab {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0rem;
  background: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #c9cfd9;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

p.tab-txt {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.footer-tab ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #c9cfd9;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer-tab li {
  float: left;
}

.footer-tab .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #fff;
}

.footer-tab li a {
  display: block;
  color: #3f5370;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  color: white;
}

.footer-tab-img a:hover {
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  color: white;
}


/*footernavtab*/
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--footer-tab-section-->
<div class="footer-tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="img-01 w-25">
      <a href="#">

        <span class="footer-tab-img">
     <img src="/Image/users.png">
     </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Setting</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="img-02 w-25">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active ">
        <span class="footer-tab-img">
      <img src="/Image/personal-card.png">
      </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Spaces</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="img-03 w-25">
      <a href="#">

        <span class="footer-tab-img">
       <img src="/Image/book.png">
       </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Exercises</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="img-04 w-25">
      <a href="#" class="active">
        <span class="footer-tab-img">
        <img src="/Image/first-aid-kit.png">
        </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Profile</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--end footer-tab-section-->
```

Comment: <a href="#" class="nav-link **active** " > This is what makes your navbutton active. Remove this so it is not active. Add this to a button to make it active again.

Comment: sir/madam did you mean i should apply this `<a href="#" class=" active " >`

Comment: Yes, i just edited it so the Active is **bold**. The active class makes the button active. If you want this to correspond to the page you are on at that time, add the active class to that button on that specific page.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the <a> tag is not part of the active class. The thing that makes it blue is the Active class. **class=" active"**

Comment: sir.madam, can you please put the answer box, im try it not work

Comment: Did you hand code this or did you copy this over?

Comment: sir,madam its a hand code ,no copy ,im try it now, but not work

Comment: I mean did you copy over this nav from bootstrap or did you hand code this? I am trying to awnser your question by using your code but its quite a mess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154205/discussion-between-core114-and-granny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap there is a class called **active**. Wich makes the navlink that contains this class (in this example its navlink 4) highlighted.

```
class="active"
```

```css
/*footer-navtab*/

.footer-tab .tooter-nav-tab {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0rem;
  background: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #c9cfd9;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

p.tab-txt {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.footer-tab ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #c9cfd9;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.footer-tab li {
  float: left;
}

.footer-tab .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #fff;
}

.footer-tab li a {
  display: block;
  color: #3f5370;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  color: white;
}

.footer-tab-img a:hover {
  background-color: #8bb6f3;
  color: white;
}


/*footernavtab*/
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--footer-tab-section-->
<div class="footer-tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="img-01 w-25">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link  ">
        <span class="footer-tab-img">
      <img src="/Image/personal-card.png">
      </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Nav1</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="img-02 w-25">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link  ">
        <span class="footer-tab-img">
      <img src="/Image/personal-card.png">
      </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Nav2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="img-03 w-25">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link  ">
        <span class="footer-tab-img">
      <img src="/Image/personal-card.png">
      </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Nav3</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="img-04 w-25">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active ">
        <span class="footer-tab-img">
      <img src="/Image/personal-card.png">
      </span>
        <p class="tab-txt">Nav4</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--end footer-tab-section-->
```

Comment: Sir, that is really good , now  i'm added for this my code, i had small issue ,i'm click nav2 but display previous  active button again

Comment: @core114 Could you elaborate your problem a bit more?

Comment: @core114 If you mean that when you switch a page nav4 is still set as active, thats because nav4 contains the **active** class. To change this remove the **active** class from nav4 and add **active** to nav2

Comment: sir, why cant be added automatically

Comment: sir, yes i mean it , when i switch a page nav4 is still set as active,

Comment: @core114 Why would you want to automate such a simple thing? Its literally removing active from one and adding it to another.

Comment: Each link refers to a page right? On each page you set the corresponding navlink to active using the class (in the code). So when you visit that page the current page is highlighted in your navbar.

Comment: sir, its a manually, its not good solution for my application,because when i click   the Nav2 i need to be remove previous   nav4 active option

Comment: sir, previous page set as active issue and  link issue, i removed the `active` class and i'm added  link for each others ,  example `<a href="nav-4" class="nav-link active "></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve the issue, but outside bootstrap. It is a pity that basig bootstrap.js does not have this function that automatically moves the active state from one nav element to another...

I used this JS solution at the end to highlight active navigation menu:

https://codepen.io/gearmobile/pen/bByZdG

```
$( '#topheader .navbar-nav a' ).on( 'click', function () {
$( '#topheader .navbar-nav' ).find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
$( this ).parent( 'li' ).addClass( 'active' );
});
```

Comment: Hi, You provided Bootstrap Nav bar, that one is  not  a my issue